# Unit of digital numbers?

Tags: digital, adc

what is the unit of digital numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit. For example what is the unit of the difference of two ADC values:

- 10 - 2 = 8 digits
- 10 - 2 = 8 units
- 10 - 2 = 8 symbols
- 10 - 2 = 8 ???

Or for example I want to describe a slope:

- Temperature example: 2 °C per second = 2 °C/sec
- ADC example: 2 ??? per second = 2 ???/sec

What is correct?

Best regards
Zlatan

Answer (score 1):

Numbers don't have units by default. Units are simply a multiplied symbol that represents the "nature" of the quantity.

Comment: Okay. Than what would you suppose to add as "symbol"?

Comment: @Zlatan Nothing!

Comment: Than how would you describe a slope (see example in my question)?

Comment: @Zlatan It would be `1/sec` or `sec^(-1)`. Like Hz (hertz), which is `1/sec`. There are tons of quantities in physics that have such units, such as the [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber#Definition), which has units of `1/meter`, because it's defined as `1/wavelength`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all figure out the LSB (least significant bit) of the ADC.

Example: The ADC uses a vref of 1.2V and has 8bit => LSB=1.2V/(2^8-1)=4.7mV

A typical temperature sensor using a bipolar junction has about -2mV/K. The example ADC with LSB=4.7mV will respond with a change of 1LSB per 2.35K temperature decrease.
A change of 1LSB/second means you have a change of -2.35K/per second.
If this isn't accurate enough for your application you can use an ADC with more bits or stack several diodes acting as temperature sensors.

If you use something else than a bipolar junction the sensitivity of the temperature sensor can be different. Just check the spec of the sensor and the ADC (and it's reference to calculate the LSB)

Parameters you need:

- Reference voltage of the ADC
- Number of bits of the ADC (to calculate LSB)
- Temperature coefficient of the sensor